# installed nginx to centos7 VPS but DNS breaks

Tags: nginx, dns, centos7, vps, nginx-config

I've got an unmanaged VPS running Centos7, I have multiple domains (with external registrar, each eventually to be running nodejs+mongo or django) which I want to run from the server.

I initially installed [MaraDNS](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-maradns-on-centos-7) to handle the DNS this which worked fine (e.g. [iwantscones.uk](http://iwantscones.uk)). But I was then recommended to install nginx onto the server.

Nginx is new to me, I've installed it and it seems to be running correctly and the domains are hitting the webserver but when nginx is started the external domains no longer resolve to the appropriate directories. I assume nginx is overriding the settings of MaraDNS and that I need to setup the mapping to directories again within the nginx environment but can't find clear instructions for this - and the only clear instructions are for setups using `sites-available` which isn't part of the CentOS7 install.

When nginx is enabled I get a "404 Not Found" on the domain but it's certainly hitting the correct web server because 'nginx/1.17.4' is stated underneath.

I have tried copying test files to the below folder path but these don't appear so I assume nginx DNS isn't setup correctly but I'm struggling to find useful direction:

```
home/nginx/iwantscones.uk/public_html
```

Any advise welcome, apoligies for the newbie questions.

I've added the varios config files below for clarity:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    index index.html index.html

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/domains/*.conf;
}
```

/etc/nginx/domains/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;
    root   /usr/share/nginx;

    location / {

    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/block.conf;
}
```

/etc/nginx/domains/iwantscones.uk.conf

```
upstream node_nginx {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.iwantscones.uk iwantscones.uk;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;
    error_log /home/nginx/iwantscones.uk/log/error.log error;
    root   /home/nginx/iwantscones.uk/public_html;

    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        # prevents 502 bad gateway error
        proxy_buffers 8 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://iwantscones.uk/ ;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /home/nginx/iwantscones.uk/public_html;
    }

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/block.conf;
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/block.conf

```
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; expires 30d; }
location ~ /\.          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
location ~ ~$           { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
location ~ /\.git { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
location = /nginx.conf { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

Comment: Hey Rich. I don't think this has anything to do with your DNS configuration. DNS seems to hit your webserver, which is all it's suppose to do. Resolve domains to IPs, not to locations. So that should be good. Can you please post your full nginx and `server { }` block?

Comment: thanks a lot @Raul , I've added the various conf files / server{} blocks - hopeuflly these are the correct ones.